# Fedora - how to downgrade to a specific package version?

Tags: fedora, packages, dnf

**How to downgrade to a specific package version not available with plain `dnf downgrade <package>`?**

---

For example, the Linux kernel my Fedora 23 came out with (`kernel-4.6.4-201.fc23.i686`) must be downgraded to a specific version `4.4.9`, for some project-specific reason.

How can I downgrade (using `dnf`) the kernel package to `kernel-4.4.9-300.fc23.i686`?

---

The problem is this command:

```
$ dnf downgrade kernel
```

only proposes to install kernel version `kernel-4.2.3-201.fc23.i686`, which is not the version I want.

The packages I need can be found for example on the **koji** website:

http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=760145

but I don't know how to request a `dnf install` from there.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just apply `dnf downgrade` to RPMs that you downloaded yourself.

In your example, in case of the kernel packages, download the RPMs you want from [Koji](https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kernel/4.4.9/300.fc23/i686) and install them using `dnf downgrade`:

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir kernel/
cd kernel/
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/kernel/4.4.9/300.fc23/i686/kernel-4.4.9-300.fc23.i686.rpm
[... and the other packages you need to downgrade ...]
dnf downgrade *.rpm
```

Not all package versions are available in the mirrors.

Comment: `dnf downgrade package.rpm` worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you get `Error: conflicting requests` you need to increase the `installonly_limit` value on `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`.